# What does "what do we do?" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> They were standing on the edge of a huge chessboard, behind the
>   black chessmen, which were all taller than they were and carved from
>   what looked like black stone. Facing them, way across the chamber,
>   were the white pieces. Harry, Ron and Hermione shivered slightly ––
>   the towering white chessmen had no faces. 
>       "Now **what do we do**?" Harry whispered. 
>       "It's obvious, isn't it?" said Ron. "We've got to play our way across the room."
>    Behind the white pieces they could see
>   another door.
>    "How?" said Hermione nervously.
>    "I think,"
>   said Ron, "we're going to have to be chessmen."
>    He walked up to
>   a black knight and put his hand out to touch the knight's horse. At
>   once, the stone sprang to life. The horse pawed the ground and the
>   knight turned his helmeted head to look down at Ron.
>   "Do we ––
>   er –– have to join you to get across?"
>   The black knight
>   nodded.
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is *what* the same as in [**What** are those things on the table?](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/what), or does the clause have some other meanings? For example, *what* is not a pronoun but an adverb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English 'anaphoric' words - words which 'stand for' other constituents of a sentence - are all called **pronouns**, but in fact there are two different categories:

- words which act as placeholders for **nominal** expressions (*he, she, it, what, which, who, this, that* &c)
- words which act as placeholders for **adverbial** expressions, and might better be called **pro-adverbs** (*how, where, when, why, whither*, &c)

But for **adjectival** expressions we have only the demonstrative *such* (now little used in this sense) and we have nothing for **verbal** expressions. Instead we use the pro-nouns and pro-adverbs in various combinations.

- With adjectives we mostly use *how+ADJ* or *what/which+NOUN* as interrogatives/relatives and *this/that/so/yay+ADJ* or *this/that+NOUN* as demonstratives.

  > How big you want that? ... About yay big.
  >   What color shirt was he wearing? ... That color.
- With verbs we mostly use *what/which* (interrogative/relative) and *this/that* (demonstrative), in combination with the all-purpose verb *DO*.

  > Whatcha doin? ... Whatchu see.
  >   What do we do? ... What we have to do.

You could make a case for thinking of *DO* here as a **pro-verb** and **what** as its obligatory pronominal object.

Comment: I read a words 'interrogative phrase' in CGEL (p.95) and it designates, i guess, your phrase, 'how big', what color shirt'.

Comment: @Listenever I thought I was just being whimsical, but it turns out that *pro-verb* is a [**recognized**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-verb) category.

Answer (score 2):

It's the usual [what](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/what) used to ask information about somebody/something.

> What is your name?

> What does he do?

> What do we do, now?

> What time is it?

In all those sentences, *what* is an interrogative pronoun.